# Grep a word from XML file with grep/sed

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sed, grep

I am working on a linux shell script to find information in a xml file using grep. The information I need is the Username wipis_dxu without the  tag. I am not allowed to use tools like xgrep or something else.

```
<Parameter displayName="Server" id="Server">
 <value>dxstg.target_domain</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter isRequired="true" displayName="User name" id="Username">
  <value>wipis_dxu</value>
</Parameter>
<Parameter isRequired="true" displayName="Password" id="Password">
  <value>wovon_man_nicht_reden_kann_darueber_muss_mann_schweigen</value>
</Parameter>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed -nr '/Username/{n;s#.*>(.*)<.*#\1#p}' file
wipis_dxu
```

Brief explanation,

- `/Username/`: find Username
- `n`: Read the next line of input
- `s#.*>(.*)<.*#\1#p`: extract the string between `> ... <`

Comment: I agree sed is a better tool for this but OP was asking for a grep solution initially...

Comment: The `sed` tag also attached in the question, so I try to offer the most suitable one I can think.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sed` and `grep` to handle XML, use an XML-aware tool. For example, in a tool I maintain called [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can write

```
xsh -I file.xml 'echo //Parameter[@id="Username"]/value'
```

Comment: I know but I am only a trainee for the governance and we have very high security standards I cannot download or use anything here that is not approved

Comment: "High security standards" and "parsing XML by sed/grep" are contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

**GREP only**

This is a bit tricky because grep matches line by line, and on the line of the username there is nothing specifically saying it's the username and not the password.

So you'll have to chain greps :

`grep -A 1 "Username" file | grep -o -P '[^>]+(?=</v)'`

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -r "wipis_dxu"
```

Will search current directory and all sub-directories for "wipis_dxu".