# How to store a value grepped out from an xml file into avariable in python?

Tags: python, xml, variables

I have an xml file with me , which has a large content with multiple records, The content would be something similar to the below one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ImpactRadiusResponse><Records page="1" numpages="12" pagesize="20000" total="233271" start="0" end="19999" uri="/Mediapartners/IR5QDjJkZKyS41206FcE662iAPP89TKhU1/Reports/mp_performance_by_subid_by_day?START_DATE=2019-06-11&amp;END_DATE=2019-09-08&amp;PUB_CAMPAIGN=0&amp;SHOW_DATE=1&amp;SHOW_SHAREDID=1&amp;SHOW_SUBID1=1&amp;SHOW_SUBID2=1&amp;SHOW_SUBID3=1" firstpageuri="/Mediapartners/IR5QDjJkZKyS41206FcE662iAPP89TKhU1/Reports/mp_performance_by_subid_by_day?PageSize=20000&amp;Page=1&amp;SHOW_SHAREDID=1&amp;START_DATE=2019-06-11&amp;SHOW_DATE=1&amp;END_DATE=2019-09-08&amp;PUB_CAMPAIGN=0&amp;SHOW_SUBID1=1&amp;SHOW_SUBID2=1&amp;SHOW_SUBID3=1" previouspageur
```

Can someone let me know a way to store the value of string "**numpages**" from the xml content .. i.e "12" into a variable called  '**pages**' in python ?

Comment: The proper way to do it would be to parse the XML file with some XML tool (such as ElementTree) and extract the value of `numpages` (an attribute on the `Records` element). See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the 'grep' functionality in linux/bash . I meant to filter out the numpages and save it's value in a variable

Comment: Using grep for XML is not a very good idea, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45954561/407651

Comment: Just seconding the comment of not `grep`ing an XML. It will likely make you very sorry someday.

Comment: @mzjn , PMende yeah.. I wasn't planning on using 'grep' .. just was referring to it in the initial comment in a literal way..  :D .. but. I got your point there..